# Need to convert NSData to NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I am pulling down a plist from a URL using an NSURLConnection, which returns an 
NSData object. I would like to convert this to an NSArray. Can anyone help me?

I am refactoring a method that currently does a synchronous request to the URL,
using arrayWithContentsOfURL: to get the NSArray.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `+[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:]` to convert the data, then check if the result `-isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSKeyedArchiver for archiving object to data.

NSKeyedUnarchiver for unarchiving object from data:

```
NSArray *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:self.receivedData];
```

Comment: Please don't re-post your answers word-by-word, but if you find another question provides an answer to this question, too, mark it as a duplicate of that question.