# How can i convert a NSData to NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdata

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to convert NSArray to NSData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata)
>   [Need to convert NSData to NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255430/need-to-convert-nsdata-to-nsarray)

HI,
I have a NSData object named as "myNsData"(it is converted form of NSArray)
and a NSarray named as "myNsArray.
can any one provide me a code to convert a NSData to NSArray?

Answer (score 30):

See this post... [Convert NSArray to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata)

The last comment deals with the reverse....

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]
```

Comment: Hey, this answer must be accepted!

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure but can you try

```
   NSArray *myNsArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myNsData];
```

Comment: What is the point of duplicating an answer that is already here? Particularly if you're not sure?

Comment: There was some problem with my connection. @Simons answer was not loaded at the time i answered. So i cudn't see his answer

Comment: This is better because it has a semicolon at the end :D

Comment: Hahahahhaha... Good one @SuperFace but it dont help me....